# 'array' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std

I receive the following error:

> 'array' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type.

I changed my compiler to g++ 4.9.  Still having issues.  I think that I may have an old version of the std library but am not sure on how to proceed to fix that.

```
#ifndef DBINTERFACE_H_
#define DBINTERFACE_H_

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <array>

class DBInterface {
private:
    double Found_Buffer[100][59];
    int Found_Count;
    double New_Buffer[100][59];
    std::array<double, 5> BLAH;

    int New_Count;
    double M[59];
    double B[59];
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

public:
    DBInterface();
    virtual ~DBInterface();
    void Update();
    void Search();
    void Add2DB();
    void Add2Buffer(double Found_Objects[][59], double New_Objects[][59]);
    void Build();

    /*
     * To be added:
     * void CollapseBuffer();
     * void DetDynamic();
     *
     */
};

#endif /* DBINTERFACE_H_ */
```

Error messages:

```
17:20:06 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project CANS ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/DBInterface.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/derek/soci/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/DBInterface.d" -MT"src/DBInterface.d" -o "src/DBInterface.o" "../src/DBInterface.cpp"
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/array:35:0,
                 from ../src/DBInterface.h:17,
                 from ../src/DBInterface.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
In file included from ../src/DBInterface.cpp:8:0:
../src/DBInterface.h:24:7: error: ‘array’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
  std::array<double, 5> BLAH;
       ^
../src/DBInterface.cpp: In function ‘void Add2Buffer(double (*)[59], double (*)[59])’:
../src/DBInterface.cpp:44:6: warning: unused variable ‘NoOfFO’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int NoOfFO;
      ^
../src/DBInterface.cpp:45:6: warning: unused variable ‘NoOfNO’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int NoOfNO;
      ^
make: *** [src/DBInterface.o] Error 1

17:20:08 Build Finished (took 2s.464ms)
```

Comment: And you're sure your'e compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Please show your compiler line.

Comment: I am not positive. How would I be sure?/ how would I change that? Edit Added.

Comment: I guarantee you you are **not** compiling in C++11 mode, that's what the "#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard." error means. Look at the **first** error, because the later errors are caused by that. The first error tells you why you get the "'array' in namespace 'std' does not name a type" error, and even tells you how to fix it! But you've ignored it, why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just read what the compiler is telling you!

`/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`

That tells you that you have included a C++11 header (in this case `<array>`) but you are not compiling in C++11 mode.

It even tells you how to fix the problem (use `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`).

The later error saying `array` doesn't name a type is because you've included a C++11 header without enabling C++11, so if you fix the **first** error then the later ones will go away.

When reading compiler errors start at the top and fix the first one, don't just pick a random part of the output to fix. Later errors are often caused by the earlier ones, so fix the earlier ones first.

Comment: You're right. Stupid mistake. It's fine now. My annotations in my IDE doesn't reflect the change however. I'm using eclipse. Do you know how to make the change. Not a huge deal, just annoying.